# Android rotation prevents from .post() or UI thread running, related to network call

Tags: android, multithreading, post, orientation

In my application, I cannot edit any UI elements after a screen orientation is changed.

1. Defined in FragmentActivity:
   static Handler uiHandler;
2. Runned in Fragment in separate thread:

uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {                                     public void run() {                                                                 chcemhovoritback.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        }
}

I have runned one post() already in application
and I if I run it before orientation changed, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When orientation changes, the activity is recreated. To prevent this from happening, add the following to the `<activity>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` (I wonder why it's not the default behavior):

```
<activity
        ...
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
```